# 800-1000V -> 5V step-down regulator

Tags: power-electronics, step-down

I need idea to design 800-1000V to 5V 1W buck regulator.

I have a very narrow space so I don't want to use flyback controller. Maybe monolithic ones.

Do you know any ic or any idea?

Comment: 1 kV and very narrow space sounds like a good mixture for fireworks.

Comment: It should be PFM for sure. Just build a normal buck. But if size matters so much, you have a problem: for such voltage all components will be quite big. Actually a small transformer would not really increase the size, i think

Comment: By the way. Maybe you could explain a little bit about the application, because people raise eyebrows and downvote, while you may have very good reasons for such specs.

Comment: Narrow space and 1kV do not mix very well.  Safety should be prioritized...

Comment: There is 700V integrated controller if i can  divide voltage by 2 some way i can use these controllers. But simple resistor divider go hot i think . 800V DC comes from AC . Will AC divider better?

Comment: In some cases phase to phase voltage can rise above 500-550VAC and i have only P-P.

Comment: "I have a very narrow space" - exactly how much space do you have, and why?

Comment: If galvanic isolation isn't required maby you should use something like in this photo?
https://circuitdigest.com/sites/default/files/circuitdiagram/transformerless-supply-circuit.png

Comment: By the way, for ac application you could start from capacitor divider.

Comment: Another by the way: circuit may be submerged to oil to be more compact under higher voltage. If you do this, don't forget to tell how it goes.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Assuming he's still alive. :)

Comment: May i ask for online video casting?

Comment: If you wonder Istanbul why not:) and sorry i can't submerge in oil . Trace clearance ok. i just try to make component sizes small as possible and area of total product. No need for isolation but zener system heats maybe a problem.

Comment: Is something drawing significant _current_ at 1000 VAC?  If so, you could maybe steal power from the magnetic field rather than make direct electrical contact with the high voltage.  I've heard of power companies using that trick to power sensors that are clamped on to high-voltage lines.  I've heard of sensors that can steal enough power for a WiFi radio from a line that is carrying as little as ten Amperes.

Comment: Good idea. Use a current tranaformer, so when there is load, some power is available on the other side. And you can even store it if load is not always available

Comment: @jameslarge it could be but 1W is too much for that i guess. Energy harvesting devices works with miliwatts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I thought:

**1- TRANSFORMERLESS SOLUTION**

If you go for a transformerless power supply approach (i.e. reducing the voltage with series capacitor) then the series capacitor will be quite big and power dissipation for other series elements (if any, e.g. regulators, resistors etc) will be high for required output current.

**2- FLYBACK CONVERTER**

Even if you design a flyback converter, the spikes at primary side will be extremely high and snubbing them will be hard. Choosing the primary MOSFET and primary-side snubbers will be problematic.

**3- CONVENTIONAL BUCK CONVERTER**

Duty-cycle will be around %0.625 at 800VDC input. From \$V_L = L \ di/dt\$, required L will be high. You can increase the frequency to decrease L but what about the pulse width when D<<1?

---

So,

- You can make a converter consisting of cascade-connected sub-converters (can be any combination of the ones above), or
- You can go for the conventional "step-down transformer + rectifier + capacitor + linear regulator" approach.

Comment: Low duty cycle just means constant pulse width and frequency modulation.

Comment: Thanks for answer it's look like these are only options for me . Now i need to make some calculations for which one is best suited. Thanks

Comment: @Gregory You're right but I meant that the pulse width will be extremely low. For example, if f=20kHz and D=0.625% then the pulse width will be 313ns. I think that it will not be a pulse, it will be a triangular "thing" instead.

Comment: Make it 1kHz. Should be enough. Besides, thank you, i needed someone to say i am right after that day...

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution i found. First divide voltage by 2 with caps(around 10uF) after that using st's integrated 800V mos buck controller Viper06 to make 12V and than standart regulator to make 5V. St not essential many companies have 600-700V controller.

Comment: So capacitor divider, bridge (or diode?) then viper?